# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 context adds "1" to table name.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I don't have any idea why it happens. 
I have DbContext which inherits from IdentityDbContext:

```
public class TestContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public TestContext()
            : base("name=DomainModelContainer")
        {
        }

        //   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        //  {
        //       throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        //   }

        public virtual DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            //modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

So when I try to execute simple code. Something like

```
var testContext = new TestContext();
testContext.AspNetRoles.Count();
```

I get an exception `Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetRoles1'`

Why EF decides to add "1" to table name? What is the point?

Comment: When you view the database generated by Code First, does it already have an AspNetRoles table?

Comment: @m.casey Actually I use Model First

Comment: Oh, in that case you check the name of your AspNetRoles entity in your EDMX file. Does it say AspNetRoles1? There should be two properties: one with the name of the entity (class) and the other with the name of the table to which it maps.

Comment: @m.casey No, I searched AspNetRoles1 everywhere but with no luck